# IP Bloqueado acesso remoto mysql linux debian

Tags: mysql, linux, lamp

Estou com o seguinte erro: 
[exec] mysqladmin: connect to server at '179.111.225.163' failed
[exec] error: 'Access denied for user 'rqtecnologia'@'177.21.38.34' (using password: YES)'

- ja alterei a senha do usuário
- ja fui no arquivo my.cnf comentei a linha bind-address = 0.0.0.0, a linha skip-networking ja vem desabilitada.
- ja habilitei o firewall iptables para a porta do mysql e para o número de ip
- ja dei todos os privilégios para o usuário, o mesmo está como rqtecnologia %

Alguém tem alguma sugestão por favor, porque eu não sei mais o que tentar.

Comment: Não custa tentar um `flush privileges`.

Answer (score 1):

Logue-se no servidor MYSQL via SSH:

```
ssh root@servidormysql
```

Logue-se no seu servidor MYSQL:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Dê permissões para o usuário `rqtecnologia` conectar ao banco `teste1`:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON teste1.* TO 'rqtecnologia'@'177.21.38.34' IDENTIFIED BY 'senhadousuário';


flush privileges;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privilege-system.html

Answer (score 0):

Você tem acesso root a esse banco de dados?

Se sim instale o mysql workbench e conecte-se ao seu servidor com o usuário root. Na área de usuários, provavelmente esse usuário vai estar limitado a um host "localhost" ou "127.0.0.1", nesse campo você coloca "%" para liberar totalmente, mas te aconselho a criar um novo usuário com as mesmas permissões e no host coloque apenas o ip "177.21.38.34" que é o ip que está tentando acessar.

Você só tem que lembrar de alterar caso o ip mude.

Caso use o phpMyAdmin é só ir nos usuários que você terá acesso aos usuários do mysql também.

Lembrando em caso de phpmyadmin nunca altere o usuário "root".

Comment: Então esse usuário já esta liberado totalmente (%).  Eu tenho acesso ao root sim, só que eu estava fazendo tudo por linha de comando, pois eu tenho acesso ao servidor através do putty.

Comment: assim entendi, como você executou o comando do mysqladmin?

Comment: Tenho aqui na empresa um server hospedado com o nosso site. Mas quem é responsável por atualizar o site, é um terceiro. E quando esse terceiro tenta subir uma atualização esta dando esse erro, entende? Mas para testar eu dou o seguinte comando:  mysqladmin -h177.21.38.34 -u rqtecnologia -p****** ver e da erro também